# String compare in "if-clause" in loop in R leads to "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"?

Tags: r, if-statement, string-comparison

I am puzzled by this behavior in R.  I just want to do a simple string compare of a list of strings produced by strsplit.  So do not understand why the following first two code pieces do what I expected, while the third is not.

```
> for (i in strsplit("A text I want to display with spaces", " ")) { print(i) }
[1] "A"       "text"    "I"       "want"    "to"      "display" "with"    "spaces"
```

Ok, this makes sense ...

```
> for (i in strsplit("A text I want to display with spaces", " ")) { print(i=="want") }
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Ok, this too.  But, what is wrong with the following construction?

```
> for (i in strsplit("A text I want to display with spaces", " ")) { if (i=="want")     print("yes") }
Warning message:
In if (i == "want") print("yes") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why doesn't this just print "yes" when the fourth word is encountered?  What should I change to have this desired behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `strsplit` produces a *list* of split strings (in this case with length 1, because you only gave it a single string to split).

```
ss <- strsplit("A text I want to display with spaces", " ")
for (i in ss[[1]]) {
  if (i=="want")     print("yes")
}
```

You can see what's going on if you just print the elements:

```
for (i in ss) {
  print(i)
}
```

the first element is a `character` vector.

Depending on what you're doing you might also consider vectorized comparisons such as `ifelse(ss=="want","yes","no")`

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the clarification!  It was the second test which confused me: i=="want" produced a check over all words in the first character vector, instead of using i as index in the resulting vector.